# Email template td widths change based on content in outlook only

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have a table containing two <td's> which are set to fixed widths but they seem to change depending on there content on outlook only...

If I put a test image in each <td'> they align fine and are equal width and the same if I put text in each but if I put a image in one  and text in the other the image one grows and the text one shrinks despite the image being a fixed size to fit its container.

This only happens on outlook and looks fine on everything else:

Here is a link to litmus to see the issue:

https://litmus.com/checklist/emails/public/ef3ee40#ol2007

And below is the code with three examples which is the same structure but just different content:

<img'> <img'>

<img'> <text'>

<text'> <text'>.

```
<!--Section content starts here-->
<table align="left" valign="middle" width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="col-12" >

   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="660" class="col-12">
         <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="col-12">
            <!--Two columns-->
            <tr>

               <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <img class="img-12" width="290" border="0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x290" style="display:block;border:none;width:100%;max-width:290px" />
               </td>

               <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <img class="img-12" width="290" border="0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x290" style="display:block;border:none;width:100%;max-width:290px" />
               </td>

            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>


   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="660" class="col-12">
         <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="col-12">
            <!--Two columns-->
            <tr>

               <!--Left image section-->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <img class="img-12" width="290" height="290" border="0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x290" style="display:block;border:none;width:100%;max-width:290px" />
               </td>

               <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;display:block;width:290px"> 
                     Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>

                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;">Take a look <a href="https://skyacomms.grouptreehosting.net/tracker.axd?t=620cced4b420f1b17e8f2d3e&u=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skyacademystudios.com%2f" style="color:#eeabff;text-decoration: underline;font-weight:600;">here</a></p>
               </td>

            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>

 <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="660" class="col-12">
         <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="col-12">
            <!--Two columns-->
            <tr>

               <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;display:block;"> 
                     Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>

                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;">Take a look <a href="https://skyacomms.grouptreehosting.net/tracker.axd?t=620cced4b420f1b17e8f2d3e&u=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skyacademystudios.com%2f" style="color:#eeabff;text-decoration: underline;font-weight:600;">here</a></p>
               </td>

               <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="290" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;display:block;"> 
                     Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>

                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;">Take a look <a href="https://skyacomms.grouptreehosting.net/tracker.axd?t=620cced4b420f1b17e8f2d3e&u=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skyacademystudios.com%2f" style="color:#eeabff;text-decoration: underline;font-weight:600;">here</a></p>
               </td>

            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use percentages, that will work for Outlook (& everything else). I've also taken out the width of the `<p>` (290px), since the width is already set in the `<td>` and that might confuse something on mobiles that don't have that much space available.

```
<tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="660" class="col-12">
         <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="col-12">
            <!--Two columns-->
            <tr>

               <!--Left image section-->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="50%" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <img class="img-12" width="290" border="0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x290" style="display:block;border:none;width:100%;max-width:290px" />
               </td>

               <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding: 20px;border:1px solid black" width="50%" class="col-12 mobile-padding-vertical mobile-padding-horizontal">
                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;display:block;"> 
                     Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>

                  <p style="font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color:#222323;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:15px;">Take a look <a href="https://skyacomms.grouptreehosting.net/tracker.axd?t=620cced4b420f1b17e8f2d3e&u=https%3a%2f%2fwww.skyacademystudios.com%2f" style="color:#eeabff;text-decoration: underline;font-weight:600;">here</a></p>
               </td>

            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Also as an aside, for responsive images in mobile, you'll either want to remove the height attribute (`height="290"`) or add in `style="...height:auto;"`. Otherwise the height will remain the same even on mobiles and will get warped.

I did get it working with width="290" in there, but that doesn't work for mobiles. 50% means that mobiles are responsive, as their columns will only be about 150px (rule of thumb is about 300px wide for mobiles).

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I should have probably checked my code more before posting... the width in the <p> was purely to see if I could force the td to the correct width by giving the content a fixed width (which didnt work) and I just forgot to take it out.

Regarding the widths I was always under the impression that defining fixed widths was the correct way to go as apposed to %'s but if %'s work I mean why not.... although it would be nice to know why this problem occurs and it changes itself for no apparent reason....

Thanks again

Comment: I've never got a fixed width approach to work. I define a width once on the outermost table (Outlook-only --- the others get a width:100% and max-width:600px), and the rest will be percentage based. Conceptually, that makes a lot more sense too, particularly when you are thinking about mobile and tablets too. You ask why? I did try and understand why too - but we're talking about a Microsoft Word rendering engine, rather than a web standard engine! So, I decided that search was fruitless!